# $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2x^{n}-x^{2n})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Consider $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(2x^{n}-x^{2n}\right)$$. Find its set of
>   convergence and and function defined as $f(x) =
>  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2x^{n}-x^{2n})$ on that set.

As far as I understand, I can consider this series separately, namely

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2x^{n}-x^{2n}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2x^{n} -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n} = 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n} -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n} = 2 \frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{1}{1-x^2}$$

And the set of convergence to the function above is $|x|<1$.

Am I right?

Comment: If $x=1$, then we get infinite sum of 1.

Comment: It certainly converges if $|x|\lt 1$.  Depending on the course, you may have to justify the splitting. You also need to check that there is divergence elsewhere. (It could be that because of cancellation the radius of convergence is greater than the individual radii.) That does not happen in this example since if $|x|\ge 1$ the terms do not even go to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The general coefficient is 
$$\begin{cases}a_{2n}=1\\a_{2n-1}=2\end{cases}$$
You may use *Hadamard's formula*:
$$\frac 1r=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\, a_n^{\frac1n}=1.$$
Alternatively, the radius of convergence is the supremum of the $r$ such that $$a_nr^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$
which is clearly $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Your result is correct, but one should exercise a little caution when manipulating infinite series. That is, you must either prove the series is absolutely convergent to rearrange terms as you have, or interpret it formally as a limit of a finite series. The latter is perhaps most instructive:
$$ \begin{split}
\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^N (2x^n-x^{2n}) &= \lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\frac{2(1-x^{N+1})}{1-x} - \frac{1-x^{2N+2}}{1-x^2}\right] \\
&= \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{2(1-x^{N+1}+x-x^{N+2})-1+x^{2N+2}}{1-x^2} \\
&= \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1+2x - x^{N+1}(2+2x-x^{N+1})}{1-x^2} \\
&= \frac{1+2x}{1-x^2} - \frac{1}{1-x^2}\lim_{N\to\infty} x^N(2+2x-x^N)
\end{split} $$

Now we wave our hands and see if $|x|\geq1$, the limit diverges. If $|x|<1$, then we get the "expected" result. So if we get the same result, why all the extra effort? Infinity can be tough sometimes -- here is a fun link:
https://plus.maths.org/content/when-things-get-weird-infinite-sums

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
r&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2x^n-x^{2n}}{2x^{n+1}-x^{2(n+1)}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2-x^{n}}{2x-x^{n+2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{x}\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2-x^{n}}{2-x^{n+1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{x}
\end{align}

For convergence we require $|r|>1$ which results in $|x|<1$.